# Invalid location of tag (form) in JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp

here is my code, I have used this code in jsp now when i am using form tag it is showing--invalid location of tag (form)

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body classPadding">
<form role="form" id="js-upload-form" > //INVALID LOCATION OF TAG(FORM)
<div class="col-sm-8 md-pl-0">
<div class="form">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" name="econoDataFile"     accept="image/*" id="js-upload-files">
</div>
<h5 id="id-text-setting">Upload an Image of size                                                        192*192</h5>
<img id="output" src="" class="save-img" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" id="js-upload-submit">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 md-pl-0">
<span>Send to a Segment</span> <select id="segment-name" class="form-control">                                              
<option value="-1" >All     Subscribers</option>            </select>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, in my case the problem was that I had the form nested inside another form